# Where was the Well of Miriam positioned within the camp of Israel, in the wilderness?

Tags: mishkan-tabernacle, dor-hamidbar

While Beni Yisroel were in the midbar (wilderness) each tribe camped and traveled in a specific arrangement surrounding the mishkan (tabernacle). In Miriam’s honor they also had a well of water that traveled along with the camp.

Is there any source that says where the well was positioned within the encampment?

Comment: Good question - are you aware of the midrash that says that the water flowed directly to all areas of the camp so they didn't actually have to go to it.

Comment: Yes. That’s part of what triggered my question. The leaders of each tribe used their staff to guide the flow of water to their banner.

Comment: Follow up question…where were the banners positioned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Midrash Tanhuma, Bamidbar 2:

> והבאר בזכות מרים, שנאמר: "ותמות שם מרים, ולא היה מים לעדה" (במדבר כ א
> ב). והיאך היתה הבאר עשויה? כמין סלע היתה מתגלגלת ובאה עמהן במסעות.
> כיון שהיו הדגלים חונים והמשכן עומד, היה הסלע בא ויושב לו בחצר אהל
> מועד, והנשיאים עומדים על גביו ואומרים: עלי באר (במדבר כא יז)
>
> And the well established in the merit of Miriam, as it says: "and
> Miriam died there, and was buried there, and there was no water for
> the congregation" (Numbers 20:1-2). And how was the well made? It was
> like a boulder that rolled and came with them on their journeys. When
> the banners were brought to a rest and the Mishkan stood, the boulder
> would come and sit in the courtyard of the Ohel Mo'ed. Then the princes
> would stand by it and say: "rise up, o well!" (Numb. 21:17)

Comment: This just raises so many more questions. Where in the courtyard? Where did the water pool? Where did the water flow out of the courtyard? Did it travel in the middle of the camp when the camp traveled?

Comment: @zaq More from R. Eliyahu Kitov: והיאך הייתה הבאר עשויה? דומה לסלע; מלא כברה מפכפכת ועולה כמפי הפך הזה. עולה עמהם להרים ויורדת עמהם לגאיות. מקום שישראל שורין - היא שורה כנגדם, במקום גבוה (בחצר אהל מועד), כנגד פתחו של אהל מועד. נשיאי ישראל באים וסובבים אותה במקלותיהם ואומרים עליה את השירה 'עלי באר ענו לה - עלי באר!' והמים מבעבעים ועולים כעמוד למעלה, וכל אחד ואחד (מן הנשיאים) מושך (את המים) במקלו, איש לשבטו ואיש למשפחתו. ואשה שהייתה צריכה לילך אצל חברתה מדגל לדגל, הייתה הולכת בספינה; - והמים היו יוצאים חוץ למחנה ומקיפים פיסא (רצועת קרקע) גדולה, ומגדלים מיני דשאים ואילנות שאין להם סוף